# Поворот актера в libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

Как в данной библиотеке можно повернуть актера на сцене?
`actor.rotateBy()` срабатывает но актер визуально не поворачивается, только где то внутри самой игры происходит поворот. Т.е я знаю место где актер повернулся, я могу с этим местом взаимодействовать(например снова повернуть актера), но визуально он остается на прежнем месте.

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Отрисовываешь актера как?

Comment: stage.addActor(actor);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно переопределить метод draw() у актера

```
public class Gem extends Actor {
        private Texture texture ;

        public Gem(float x, float y) {
            setPosition(x, y);
            texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/gem.png"));
        }
      @Override
        public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
                batch.draw(texture, getX(), getY(),
                        getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f,
                        getWidth(), getHeight(), 1, 1, getRotation());
        }
}
```

---

```
stage.addActor(new Gem(2, 6));
```

Comment: Как я могу переопределить метод у актера?
Можете подсказать?

Comment: @Erick_Voodoo, обновил ответ.

Comment: да, спасибо большое, уже получилось самому реализовать)